# slick carousel counter null value

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, slick.js

i am trying to make counter for slick slider carousel but it always turn to null in the first slide but it works when i move to the next slide , the problem only occurs when you refresh the page the first value turns to 1/null .

```
<script>
        $('.regions-slider').slick({
            dots: false,
            infinite: true,
            speed: 300,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            arrows:true,
            prevArrow:'<button type="button" class="slide-btn slide-btn-prev"><i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-left"></i></button>',
            nextArrow:'<button type="button" class="slide-btn slide-btn-next"><i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i></button>',

});

var $slider = $('.regions-slider');

  var currentSlide;
  var slidesCount;
  var sliderCounter = document.createElement('div');
  sliderCounter.classList.add('slideCount');
  
  var updateSliderCounter = function(slick, currentIndex) {
    if(slick.slideCount == null){
        slidesCount = $slider.length;
    }
    currentSlide = slick.slickCurrentSlide() + 1;
    slidesCount = slick.slideCount;
    $(sliderCounter).text(currentSlide + '/' + slidesCount);

  };

  $slider.on('init', function(event, slick) {
    $slider.append(sliderCounter);
    updateSliderCounter(slick);
  });

  $slider.on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
    updateSliderCounter(slick, currentSlide);
  });

  $slider.slick();

    </script>
```

[image: the problem]

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer in chinese website and its working :

```
  $('.regions-slider').on('init', function(event, slick) {
    $(this).append('<div class="slideCount"><span class="current"></span> / <span class="total"></span></div>');
    $('.current').text(slick.currentSlide + 1);
    $('.total').text(slick.slideCount);
  })
  .slick({
    dots: false,
            infinite: true,
            speed: 300,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            arrows:true,
            prevArrow:'<button type="button" class="slide-btn slide-btn-prev"><i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-left"></i></button>',
            nextArrow:'<button type="button" class="slide-btn slide-btn-next"><i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i></button>',
  })
  .on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
    $('.current').text(nextSlide + 1);
  });
```